# TSQL - Total working hours and money paid

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
USE databse_Live

GO


DECLARE @Site INT; SET @Site = 38;
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME, @DateTo DATETIME;
SET @DateFrom = '2017-09-01';
SET @DateTo = '2017-12-21';

SELECT 
      w.[PayrollRef],
      w.[FirstName],
      w.[LastName],
      r1s.[NationalInsurance],
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day1_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day2_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day3_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day4_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day5_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day6_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day7_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalDays,    
      --SUM(    Day1_Standard_Hours + Day2_Standard_Hours  + Day3_Standard_Hours + Day4_Standard_Hours  + Day5_Standard_Hours + Day6_Standard_Hours + Day7_Standard_Hours + 
            --Day1_Overtime_Hours + Day2_Overtime_Hours  + Day3_Overtime_Hours + Day4_Overtime_Hours  + Day5_Overtime_Hours + Day6_Overtime_Hours + Day7_Overtime_Hours +
            --Day1_Adhoc_Hours + Day2_Adhoc_Hours  + Day3_Adhoc_Hours + Day4_Adhoc_Hours  + Day5_Adhoc_Hours + Day6_Adhoc_Hours + Day7_Adhoc_Hours) AS TotalHours,
      CAST(SUM( ISNULL(r1s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day1_Standard_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r2s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day2_Standard_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r3s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day3_Standard_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r4s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day4_Standard_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r5s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day5_Standard_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r6s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day6_Standard_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r7s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day7_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL(r1O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day1_Overtime_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r2O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day2_Overtime_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r3O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day3_Overtime_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r4O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day4_Overtime_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r5O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day5_Overtime_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r6O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day6_Overtime_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r7O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day7_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL(r1a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day1_Adhoc_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r2a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day2_Adhoc_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r3a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day3_Adhoc_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r4a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day4_Adhoc_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r5a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day5_Adhoc_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r6a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day6_Adhoc_Hours], 0) + 
            ISNULL(r7a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day7_Adhoc_Hours], 0)) AS Decimal (10, 2)) AS [TotalPay],
      CAST(SUM( ISNULL((r1s.[PayRate] + r1s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r1s.[Margin] + r1s.[pension] + r1s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day1_standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r2s.[PayRate] + r2s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r2s.[Margin] + r2s.[Pension] + r2s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day2_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r3s.[PayRate] + r3s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r3s.[Margin] + r3s.[Pension] + r3s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day3_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r4s.[PayRate] + r4s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r4s.[Pension] + r4s.[Margin] + r4s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day4_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r5s.[PayRate] + r5s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r5s.[Pension] + r5s.[Margin] + r5s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day5_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r6s.[PayRate] + r6s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r6s.[Pension] + r6s.[Margin] + r6s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day6_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r7s.[PayRate] + r7s.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r7s.[Pension] + r7s.[Margin] + r7s.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day7_Standard_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r1o.[PayRate] + r1o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r1o.[Margin] + r1o.[pension] + r1o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day1_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r2o.[PayRate] + r2o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r2o.[Margin] + r2o.[Pension] + r2o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day2_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r3o.[PayRate] + r3o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r3o.[Margin] + r3o.[Pension] + r3o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day3_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r4o.[PayRate] + r4o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r4o.[Pension] + r4o.[Margin] + r4o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day4_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r5o.[PayRate] + r5o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r5o.[Pension] + r5o.[Margin] + r5o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day5_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r6o.[PayRate] + r6o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r6o.[Pension] + r6o.[Margin] + r6o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day6_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r7o.[PayRate] + r7o.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r7o.[Pension] + r7o.[Margin] + r7o.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day7_Overtime_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r1a.[PayRate] + r1a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r1a.[Margin] + r1a.[pension] + r1a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day1_Adhoc_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r2a.[PayRate] + r2a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r2a.[Margin] + r2a.[Pension] + r2a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day2_Adhoc_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r3a.[PayRate] + r3a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r3a.[Margin] + r3a.[Pension] + r3a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day3_Adhoc_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r4a.[PayRate] + r4a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r4a.[Pension] + r4a.[Margin] + r4a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day4_Adhoc_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r5a.[PayRate] + r5a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r5a.[Pension] + r5a.[Margin] + r5a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day5_Adhoc_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r6a.[PayRate] + r6a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r6a.[Pension] + r6a.[Margin] + r6a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day6_Adhoc_Hours], 0) +
            ISNULL((r7a.[PayRate] + r7a.[WorkingTimeRegulation] + r7a.[Pension] + r7a.[Margin] + r7a.[NationalInsurance]) * [Day7_Adhoc_Hours], 0)) AS decimal(10, 2))  AS [TotalCharge]


  FROM [TimesheetLine] tl

    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Timesheet]     ts      ON      tl.[TimesheetId] = ts.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Worker]        w       ON      tl.[WorkerId] = w.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r1s     ON      tl.[Day1_Standard_RateId] = r1s.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r2s     ON      tl.[Day2_Standard_RateId] = r2s.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r3s     ON      tl.[Day3_Standard_RateId] = r3s.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r4s     ON      tl.[Day3_Standard_RateId] = r4s.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r5s     ON      tl.[Day3_Standard_RateId] = r5s.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r6s     ON      tl.[Day3_Standard_RateId] = r6s.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r7s     ON      tl.[Day3_Standard_RateId] = r7s.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r1o     ON      tl.[Day1_Overtime_RateId] = r1o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r2o     ON      tl.[Day2_Overtime_RateId] = r2o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r3o     ON      tl.[Day3_Overtime_RateId] = r3o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r4o     ON      tl.[Day4_Overtime_RateId] = r4o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r5o     ON      tl.[Day5_Overtime_RateId] = r5o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r6o     ON      tl.[Day6_Overtime_RateId] = r6o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r7o     ON      tl.[Day7_Overtime_RateId] = r7o.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r1a     ON      tl.[Day1_Adhoc_RateId] = r1a.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r2a     ON      tl.[Day2_Adhoc_RateId] = r2a.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r3a     ON      tl.[Day3_Adhoc_RateId] = r3a.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r4a     ON      tl.[Day4_Adhoc_RateId] = r4a.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r5a     ON      tl.[Day5_Adhoc_RateId] = r5a.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r6a     ON      tl.[Day6_Adhoc_RateId] = r6a.[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rate]          r7a     ON      tl.[Day7_Adhoc_RateId] = r7a.[id]

 WHERE
    ts.[SiteId] = @Site
    AND ts.[datefrom] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo


GROUP BY w.[FirstName], w.[LastName], w.[PayrollRef], r1s.[NationalInsurance]

ORDER BY TotalDays  ASC
```

However, It is showing me that some people have worked 5 days but they have no hours or no money paid. eg.

[Results of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AAEP.png)

The whole point of doing this query is to find out how many days a worker has worked and what have they been paid with the total charge. I am getting the right workers with the right days worked. However, when the total hours or the total money is being calculated it is wrong as it should not be showing 0 and the same goes for the total charge

Comment: Give some sample input and the desired output...

Comment: Sample input is data taken from a time sheet in the database which records the worker hours, whether its standard, overtime or adhoc hours. Each hour type is associated with its individual rate id. desired  output is displayed above in the screenshot which shows the 3 value which are false and the rest true

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some values in the computations is evaluated to null there by reducing the whole result of totalpaid and totalcharge to zero.

I suggest you to individually select below script so that you will get to know bug.

```
    SELECT r1s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day1_Standard_Hours],
r2s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day2_Standard_Hours],
                r3s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day3_Standard_Hours],
                r4s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day4_Standard_Hours],
                r5s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day5_Standard_Hours],
                r6s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day6_Standard_Hours],
                r7s.[PayRate] * tl.[Day7_Standard_Hours],
r1O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day1_Overtime_Hours],
                r2O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day2_Overtime_Hours],
                r3O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day3_Overtime_Hours],
                r4O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day4_Overtime_Hours],
                r5O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day5_Overtime_Hours],
                r6O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day6_Overtime_Hours],
                r7O.[PayRate] * tl.[Day7_Overtime_Hours],
                r1a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day1_Adhoc_Hours],
                r2a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day2_Adhoc_Hours],
                r3a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day3_Adhoc_Hours],
                r4a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day4_Adhoc_Hours],
                r5a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day5_Adhoc_Hours],
                r6a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day6_Adhoc_Hours],
                r7a.[PayRate] * tl.[Day7_Adhoc_Hours]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it setup now, it is including days with zero hours worked as 1 day. The user might be showing 5 days but have zero hours for those days, so when you multiply the pay rate you are getting zero dollars earned.

```
SELECT 
      w.[PayrollRef],
      w.[FirstName],
      w.[LastName],
      r1s.[NationalInsurance],
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day1_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day2_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day3_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day4_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day5_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day6_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day7_Standard_Hours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalDays,
```

You need to change your query to only be greater than zero and not greater than or equal to.

```
SELECT 
      w.[PayrollRef],
      w.[FirstName],
      w.[LastName],
      r1s.[NationalInsurance],
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day1_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day2_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day3_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day4_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day5_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day6_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN Day7_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalDays,
```